# Як назвати жіночий капелюшок із великими полями?

Tags: фразеологізми, словосполучення

Як назвати модний жіночий капелюшок з великими (чи не дуже) полями?

Чи може "крислатий капелюх/капелюшик" бути жіночим, стильним, модним, молодіжним?

СУМ-11 дає такі означення, та не зрозуміло чи мають вони потрібні конотації.

> КРИСЛА́ТИЙ, а, е.
>   2. Те саме, що крисатий. Укривши голову крислатим брилем з доброї житньої соломи, Кардаш.. блукав серед пісків (Семен Журахович, Звич. турботи, 1960, 16).
>
> ПОЛЕ, я, сер.
>   8. перев. мн. Відігнуті краї капелюха, бриля тощо; криси.

**UPD:** Як сказати "ширина крисів - 10 сантиметрів", чи краще "країв"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Капелюх або бриль має *криси*, вживання слова *поля* в цьому значенні – це совіцький росіянизм 2-ї половини ХХ ст. Жодний із довоєнних словників [не дає](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on) наявности значення *криси* в слові *поля*.

Звичайно ж, крислатий жіночий капелюшок [може бути](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BA&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA%22&*) й модним, і стильним, і молодіжним. Наприклад:

> Наївні очі, юну свіжість рис
>
> Затінює крислатий капелюшок.
>
> Одна з хрестоматійних Попелюшок,
>
> Ти сниш про те, що є на світі Принц.
>
> [/Люцина Хворост. Інженю/](http://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/2270767.html)

До речи, хоча обидва варіянти слова допустимі, та все ж Ґуґл дає таке порівняння їх вживаности: [капелюш**и**к](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BA&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BA%22&*) – 282 результати, [капелюш**о**к](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=opera&q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BA&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA%22&*) – 79 100 результатів.

Comment: Розумію, що це поза темою, але можливо варто додати про береги книжок? (які теж не "поля") Ех, СУМ-20 тупо скопіював визначення "бриль" разом з "полями"... :'(

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko - Я думав про це, та, по-перше, запитання не про це, а по-друге, там більше синонімів, і «поля» теж іноді вживається. Як хочете. можете додати сюди ще одну відповідь, де й про береги буде.

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko  краще ж бо створити нове запитання, так ґуґлитиметься краще

Comment: Як сказати ширина "полів" (крисів?) - 10 сантиметрів?

Comment: @Artemix - Я б сказав «криси 10 см завширшки».